# Prevent a state change in ui-router based on HTTP query

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How do I prevent a state change for a specific "to" state in ui-router (is it using onEnter?) assuming I have this route:

```
.state('auth.confirm', {
  url: '/confirm/:resetToken',
  template: '<confirm-page></confirm-page>',
  data: { pageTitle: 'Confirm Reset', specialClass: 'gray-bg' }
})
```

and this service with this promise-based function:

```
validateResetToken: function(resetToken) {
  var self = this;
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http.post(AppConstants.hostRootUrl + '/auth/reset/validate', { resetToken: resetToken })
    .then(function(response) {
      if(response.data && response.data.success) {
        // if we got a 200 return and it indicates success in the response, resolve
        self.message = 'Success';
        deferred.resolve(self.message);
      }
      else if (response.data && !response.data.success && response.data.error) {
        // if we got a 200 return, but success is falsey and there's an error message, reject with that message
        self.message = response.data.error;
        deferred.reject(self.message);
      }
      else {
        // error with generic message
        self.message = 'Unknown response. Contact administrator.';
        deferred.reject(self.message);
      }
    }, function(errPost) {
      if (errPost.data && errPost.data.error) {
        self.message = errPost.data.error;
        deferred.reject(self.message);
      }
      else {
        self.message = 'Could not connect.';
        deferred.reject(self.message);
      }
    });

  return deferred.promise;
},
```

Comment: You can do it from the [resolve](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider) part, not from `onEnter`, because you can reject the promise returend from `validateResetToken` - It will abort the state change (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)

Comment: I tried that, maybe I was doing something wrong, but rejects didn't seem to prevent state changes?

Comment: I guess my problem was that I had `resolve: ... return AuthService.validateResetToken($stateParams.resetToken).catch(function() { toastr.error(); return null; }); ...` I was catching the rejection to do something with it. I assumed returning null would cause the same as returning a reject().

Comment: @AlonEitan, acually, you made look again and see my mistake. How can I get you some points for appreciation? :) Put your comment into a post and I'll select it.

Comment: That's OK, I put it as a comment because it's not an answer - Just a suggestion :) +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For posterity (and Googlers) sake, Alon Eitan made me take a second look at my `resolve` approach, and I realized that my addition of the `catch()` was causing the rejected promise to not percolate up. This final code works:

```
    .state('auth.confirm', {
      url: '/confirm/:resetToken',
      template: '<confirm-page></confirm-page>',
      data: { pageTitle: 'Confirm Reset', specialClass: 'gray-bg' },
      resolve: {
        validated: function($q, $stateParams, AuthService, toastr) {
          //$log.log('auth.confirm resolve $stateParams',$stateParams);
          return AuthService.validateResetToken($stateParams.resetToken).catch(function(validateErr) {
            toastr.error(validateErr, 'Blocked', {closeButton: true});
            return $q.reject(validateErr);
          });
        }
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a rule as in https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-create-rules-to-prevent-access-to-a-state

Adapt their example:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('privatePage', {
    data: {
      rule: function(token) {
        return validateResetToken(token)
      }
  });
});
app.run(function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, to) {
    if (!angular.isFunction(to.data.rule)) return;
    var result = to.data.rule($stateParams.resetToken);

    if (result && result.to) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Optionally set option.notify to false if you don't want 
      // to retrigger another $stateChangeStart event
      $state.go(result.to, result.params, {notify: false});
    }
  });
});
```